# Comparing R squared for least squares line fit and plane fit (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, least-squares

I have a set of datapoints in 3D space, and I'd like to determine quantifiably if I can ignore the y component of the data. I've computed ordinary least-squares for z = ax + b and ordinary least squares for z = ax + b*y + c. I get an R^2 value for my 2D plot and a residual (sum of squared errors) for my 3D plot. How do I go from a residual to R^2 value for the 3D plot and is this acceptable to compare to my R^2 value for my 2D plot?

```
xs = array of x data

ys = array of y data

zs = array of z data
```

For 2D:

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(xs, zs)
```

For 3D:

```
tmp_A = []
tmp_b = []
for i in range(len(xs)):
   tmp_A.append([xs[i], ys[i], 1])
   tmp_b.append(zs[i])
b = np.matrix(tmp_b).T
A = np.matrix(tmp_A)
fit = (A.T * A).I * A.T * b
errors = b - A * fit
residual = np.linalg.norm(errors)
```

Thanks!

Jason

**Edit**

Here's the answer:

```
E = np.squeeze(np.asarray(errors))
Z = np.array(zs)
r2 = 1 - (E.var() / Z.var())
```

Comment: R-squared (R2) can be calculated as "R2 = 1.0 - (absolute_error_variance / dependent_data_variance)" and using numpy arrays this is trivially easy as numpy arrays have a var() method - so the code becomes "R2 = 1.0 - (abs_err.var() / dep_data.var())"

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: Thanks James, the data I have is in "rosbag" file format and I unfortunately can't share that, but in order to test this I created some 3D points like this: https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/1db8d69b4b65e8bc66a6 . So I understand that residual in my case is the sum of the squared error, which in what you've shown is abs_err.var() I believe. So I need the dependent_data_variance, which array do I use for the dep_var when I'm using x, y, and z?

Comment: I got an answer that looks right by doing the following: Z = numpy.array(zs) and r2 = 1 - (residual / Z.var()) . Does this look correct to you?

Comment: If the dependent data is named "Z", and the fitted equation's predicted values are named "Predicted",  then my numpy calculation for R-squared (R2) would be  "R2 = 1.0 - ((Predicted - Z).var() / Z.var())" as the absolute error would then be "predicted - Z"

Comment: It works great, done!

Comment: Like, totally awesome, gnarly numpy statistics dude!